# Using Selenium IDE for a test-case which includes backend call?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I add a new category in the admin panel and want to ensure that the category is available in the dropdown on the user's part of the website. Recorded test in the Selenium IDE works fine. But the thing is, the task that I execute is of course not a pure frontend thing - the category is saved in the database and is loaded from it to show it to the user. So if something goes wrong on the database-side, the test will fail.

My question is: is it bad practice to do such tests that depend on backend-behavior ? Should I go for Selenium Webdriver ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Selenium Webdriver, your test will not change in a main thing. It still will check database side. Selenium Webdriver is just anouther tool for testing that is more flexible and allows to make more complex test then in Selenium IDE.

I don't think that it is bad practice, because it is just one of the tests that chould be executed to enshure you that this part of your project works correctly. In this case I would check back-end part(get all categories from DB or admin's panel and check that there is no extra or missing ones) and than check user's panel(all categories are the same as set in DB and admin's panel).